# Can i integrate google drive with mobile app?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am new for android development.I want to integrate google drive with my android app for storing Sqlite database files of my app.So anybody help me to how to do this???

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation: `Google Drive provides a REST API`...

I didn't have prior experience with Google Drive, but since they offer a REST API, I don't see any difficulties in integrating GD into a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for details on how to integrate with the Android app for Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui